# to import a selected theme to the next page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a set of themes for my website. I can load a certain theme on selection by user.(supposing on the home page)
Example:
1.blue
2.green
3.dark

I have created a function in jquery to establish this change(val);
Now i have to  move the selected theme to the 
next page. How to import the selected theme to the next page?

Answer (score 1):

A query string would seem to be the best approach given what little information you've provided:

```
http://myawesomesite.com?theme=blue
```

You'd then use something like this to capture the string and apply it:

[Get url parameter jquery Or How to Get Query String Values In js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

If you want the theme to persist, you'll need to use a cookie or server-side solution to store the data.

Comment: Oops. Fixed URL syntax.

Comment: +1 for "If you want the theme to persist, you'll need to use a cookie or server-side solution to store the data."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a static website. In order to pass a value to another page, is to use something called Query String.

So, in your JS code on the theme-selection page, do

```
var selected_theme = $('#selected_theme').val();
window.location = "/next_page/?selected_theme=" + selected_theme;
```

This will send the selected theme value to the next page.

I hope this makes sense... :)

Comment: The theme should change in the next page on click of the page(section). I can change the theme in all the pages but when i move from one page to another i have to retain the selected theme. Can we use cache to do this?

Comment: You can use sessions or cookies to save such data.